# Adding Drop down menu in the window heder using extjs4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs4

I need to add drop down menu when I click the top right icon on the window header display it like Google Chrome browser menu. Adding Drop down menu in the window header using extjs4.
  Here is the code, but cannot able to see the menu.
 code here:

Hi I need this looks like google chrome browser menu. i cannot see when i click the menu on window.

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var win;
    var options = [

                   {"name":"AAdvantage ",},
                   {"name":"PNR",},
                   {"name":"Bag File",}
               ];
     Ext.regModel('Options', {
         fields: [
             {type: 'string', name: 'name'}
         ]
     });

     var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         model: 'Options',
         data: options
     });


         var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                id: 'mainMenu',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Search Customer',
                        checked: true
                    }, '-',
                    {
                        text: 'Customer Information',
                        checked: true
                    }, '-', {
                        text: 'Travel History',
                        checked: true
                    }, '-', {
                        text: 'Resolution'
                    }, '-', {
                        text: 'Future OD'
                    }, '-', {
                        text: 'History OD'
                    },'-', {
                        text: 'Help',
                        checked: true
                    }, '-', {
                        text: 'Upload Document',
                        checked: true
                    }
                ]
            });
    function showContactForm() {
        if (!win) {

            var form = Ext.widget('form', {
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                border: false,
                bodyPadding: 10,

                fieldDefaults: {
                    labelSeparator: "",
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    labelWidth: 100,
                    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold'
                },
                defaults: {
                    margins: '0 0 10 0'
                },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                    fieldLabel: 'Search Customer',
                    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;padding:0',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    defaultType: 'textfield',

                    fieldDefaults: {
                        labelAlign: 'top'
                    },
                },

                    {
                     xtype: 'combobox',
                     fieldLabel: 'Select Option',
                     name: 'suit_options_id',
                     id: 'ComboboxSuitOptions',
                     typeAhead:false,
                     labelAlign:'top',
                     labelSeparator: "",
                     store: store,
                     editable: false,
                     displayField: 'name',
                     hiddenName: 'id',
                     valueField: 'id',
                     queryMode: 'local',
                     listeners: {
                            change: function(combo) {
                                 console.log(combo.getValue());
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    {

                         xtype: 'textfield',
                         fieldLabel: 'AAdvantage Number',
                        allowBlank: false

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text : 'Search',
                        handler: function() {

                        }
                    }]
            });

            win = Ext.widget('window', {
                title: '<center>FCR</center>',
                closeAction: 'hide',
                width: 200,
                height: 300,
                minHeight: 300,
                layout: 'fit',
                closable: false,
                tools: [
                         {  type:'left',
                            menu: menu
                         }
                ],
                resizable: true,
                modal: true,
                items: form
            });
        }
        win.show();
    }
    showContactForm();

});
```

Comment: This works for me when I type your code to the console. But there are some problems. I get an warning `Ext.regModel has been deprecated. Models can now be created by extending Ext.data.Model: Ext.define("MyModel", {extend: "Ext.data.Model", fields: []});.` Also, you should prefer use the `launch` method of `Ext.app.Application` to start rather than `Ext.onReady` which is ExtJS version 3

Comment: Oh, I see what is not working : you expect a toolbar !

Comment: I edited my answer. I now shows a menu. It is not correctly placed, so there is still some tuning left for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code does what it means:

```
tools: [
    {  type:'left',
        menu: menu
    }
],
```

This code generates your left icon in the top window [see the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool-cfg-type), but ool`has no property menu, so your code cannot work.

Define a `handler` function that shows your menu (this code works, but there is some tuning necessary to align the menu on the button) :

```
tools: [
    {  type:'left',
        handler: function(){menu.show()}
    }
],
```

There are also some other problems with your code.

1. I get an warning `Ext.regModel has been deprecated. Models can now be created by extending Ext.data.Model: Ext.define("MyModel", {extend: "Ext.data.Model", fields: []});`.
2. Also, you should prefer use the launch method of Ext.app.Application to start rather than Ext.onReady which is ExtJS version 3